# rsync: transferred file twice as large as original file

Tags: linux, ssh, filesystems, rsync

I have transferred a file from a client to a remote host with `rsync` through a `ssh` bridge, and now the resulting file on the remote host is more than twice as large as the original file on the client.

9.1GB -> 20GB

I have checked the size with `du -sh`. This looks wrong. Given that these files sit in two different locations, and they are quite big, how can I check what went wrong?

client and remote host are two distinct flavours of Linux

output of `ls -ls <file>` in the two locations is:

client

```
 9528947 -rw-r--r-- 1 user1 group1 20420948104 Nov  2 13:45 filename.hdf5
```

remote host

```
 19942340 -rw-r--r--. 1 user2 group2 20420948104 Nov  2 14:45 filename.hdf5
```

---

EDIT

It looks like it may be Thin provisioning

https://fedoramagazine.org/copying-large-files-with-rsync-and-some-misconceptions/

---

EDIT 2

running

```
 rsync -avz -S <origin> <dest>
```

does not solve the problem.

---

EDIT 3

The filesystem on the remote host is:

`df -Th` -> `nfs4`

Comment: Sparseness confirmed. The files are of the same size of 20420948104 bytes. The second one takes 19942340 KiB of diskspace, it's not sparse. The first one takes 9528947 KiB of diskspace, it is sparse.

Comment: If the remote host uses NFS, then there is yet another server (probably the very NFS server) that ultimately stores the file in some filesystem local to the server. If you want to save some diskspace then this is the filesystem that matters most. *If you can act on the server directly* then maybe you can use `fallocate -d` to make the file sparse in place. Even if the file still appears non-sparse via NFS, if it's sparse in the filesystem that "physically" holds it then it takes less space. If you keep updating the file, the approach may be inconvenient; for a file copied once, it may be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common cause for such a problem is that the source file is a
[sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file):

> a sparse file is a type of computer file that attempts to use file system space more efficiently when the file itself is partially empty. This is achieved by writing brief information (metadata) representing the empty blocks to disk instead of the actual "empty" space which makes up the block, using less disk space. The full block size is written to disk as the actual size only when the block contains "real" (non-empty) data.

You need the parameter `-S` or `–sparse` to tell rsync to handle
sparse files efficiently. Without it, the non-existing blocks are
still allocated on the target, thus inflating the file.

---

According to Wikipedia, sparse file were only added in
[NFS version 4.2 (RFC 7862)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System#NFSv4).

As your NFS version is 4.1, it most likely does not support
sparse files. You will need to upgrade the NFS server to the
required level.

Comment: I have used `rsync -avz -S <origin> <dest>` and the result is the same. Could it be possible that thin provisioning is not supported by the remote filesystem?

Comment: @simona In general it is possible. What is the filesystem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski nsf4 on remote host

Comment: This requires [NFSv4.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System#NFSv4). See also [How do you synchronise huge sparse files (VM disk images) between machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66338/how-do-you-synchronise-huge-sparse-files-vm-disk-images-between-machines), where it's said that [bdsync](https://github.com/TargetHolding/bdsync) can do better for this case.

Comment: @harrymc from `mount` I can see it is nfs4 v4.1 ...

Comment: Then this is the problem.

Comment: @harrymc I looked into bdsync. I think it is useful only after the files have been transferred the first time.